# Bank Account iOS App Structure

Tags: ios, objective-c

Last semester in an assignment the class had to model a bank account in C++. This semester we are doing the same thing except in objective-c and in the form of an iOS app. I've just begun and have a basic storyboard set up to test my deposits however I cannot get my total balance to add up and I'm pretty sure it is because I instantiate my Account object with the deposit IBAction. How should this be done properly? I only need a push in the right direction and I'm confident I can hit the ground running from there with the rest. See attached code:

```
- (IBAction)deposit:(id)sender {

Account *acc =[[Account alloc]init];

double damount = [_textField.text doubleValue] ;

[acc deposit:(damount)];


_display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", acc.getBalance];
}
```

Original C++ code as requested:

```
int main(){
char szFName[32];
char szLName[32];
char szSIN[12];
char szAccType[10];
double dBalance;
int op;
Account *acc[MAX_ACCOUNTS];
int count=0;
while (count<MAX_ACCOUNTS)
{
    cout << "Customer's First Name : " << flush;
    cin >> szFName;
    cout << "Customer's Last Name : " << flush;
    cin >> szLName;
    cout << "Customer's SIN : " << flush;
    cin >> szSIN;
    cout << "Account Type : " << flush;
    cin >> szAccType;
    cout << "Opening Balance : " << flush;
    cin >> dBalance;

    if ( !strcmp(szAccType,"Checking") )
        acc[count] = new CheckingAcc(szFName, szLName, szSIN, szAccType, dBalance);
    else if ( !strcmp(szAccType,"VIP") )
        acc[count] = new VIPAcc(szFName, szLName, szSIN, szAccType, dBalance);
    else if ( !strcmp(szAccType,"Saving") )
        acc[count] = new SavingAcc(szFName, szLName, szSIN, szAccType, dBalance);
    else
    {
        cout << "Incorect account type." << endl;
        continue;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: You probably want your account to persist longer the lifetime of that method.  What did you do in your other program?

Comment: Use NSLog in your `deposit` method to find out: (1) is it running at all? (2) is `_textField` nil? (3) is `_display` nil?

Comment: Also, as @BrianNickel rightly points out, you are creating an Account (`acc`) and throwing it away every time through the `deposit:` method. That sounds kind of nutty. Have you heard of instance variables (ivars)?

Comment: I agree it is nutty and with that said where can I instantiate my object so that it is not thrown away?

Comment: @BrianNickel I've updated my oroginal post with the C++ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you're creating a new bank account every time instead of maintaining a single account and adding to it.

In your original program you created an array of accounts `acc` that persisted during the lifetime of the user input.  Since you've moved from a procedural program to a UI program with a run loop, you'll need a more persistent place to store it.

Generally, a good spot would be a property on your view controller or higher up if the objects need to persist longer than the view controller:

```
@property Account *account;

...

- (id)init
{
    if (self) {
        _account = [[Account alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

...

[self.account deposit:(damount)];
```

Since this is for class, you will probably want to review your textbook for topics like properties and instance variables.